# Trigger an init script when a specific device is up and a kernel module has been loaded

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, startup, sysvinit, upstart

On my Ubuntu 12.04 servers, I need to write an *init.d* script that waits until the infiniband interface (device: *mlx4_0*, interface: *ib0*) is completely up, and until the *knem* kernel module is loaded.

I have an *init.d* script that works if I wait until the system is up and manually `service myscript start`, but it does not work if I load it normally at boot time. I'm using boot order *99*, but it does not start correctly because I need it to wait until those features are running.

What is the correct syntax in an `init.d` to achieve that (one kernel module and )? I guess there must be some keyword like `# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network` but I can't find the correct ones for specific interface and kernel modules.

For background: the init script is related to *SLURM*, *openMPI* and *infiniband* interactions. I have compiled *SLURM* with *Mellanox infiniband driver* support, and *openMPI* is linked to this version of SLURM. The result is that openMPI is using directly the mellanox infiniband driver, which is much more powerful than *ipob* (ip over inifiniband). To do that, it needs to use the registered memory of the system, which has to be set as *unlimited*.

SO:

I have added a few `logger` outputs in my *init.d* script. I notice that in fact the modules are up and running. So I don't understand fully the problem. It is strange, maybe related to some environment variables needed and that are set up only in a full user space and not at init time.

The problem concerns the memlock limits set in */etc/security/limits.conf*. To make it work I had to set

```
*             -   memlock       unlimited
root          -   memlock       unlimited
```

and in this way, when I launch the slurm deamon with an *ssh* connection everything works, and when it is the init process that starts the daemon, it is like it does not consider the rules in */etc/security/limits.conf*.

Comment: Danduk82 - it's probably a good idea to put the answer portion of your question in an answer if you can. You should feel free to accept your own answer as well. If you do this thing and ping me, I'll likely upvote it.

Comment: @mikeserv : actually, this is not the answer, it is part of the question. The rules about *memlock* seem to work only if I start the deamon with a ssh connection, and it does not work when it is started by *init*.

Comment: ahhh...  That makes sense. It went over my head before.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know specifically about an `init.d` file, but a `udev` rule for running a script upon device-add might look like:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="VID", ATTRS{idProduct}=="PID", RUN+="/path/to/executable"
```

You should do some digging in `udevadm` to learn more about the way the device is typically added and its modules loaded. You'll also find the correct values for `VID` and `PID` in there.

*Does it accept a combination of both device and kernel module?*

Yes. Well... no. Maybe? The answer to this question entirely depends on the level at which you intercept the device-add. `udev` has to do many things from the point at which it initially detects a device to the point at which it has fully loaded and initialized the device and it can be considered *up*.

Some of these things are likely:

- initially detecting the hardware on its parent bus/device/subsystem
- finding and loading the appropriate kernel module
- populating the `/dev` `devfs` file system with the appropriate device special file
- detecting any child-devices the current device adds and rinse, repeat

You can specify a rule for all or any of these levels of action. You can also `udevadm` `trigger` or `monitor` or several other things directly in real-time to determine exactly what these levels of action might be.

I recommend you look closely at [this information](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) if you wish to become more familiar with it.

Comment: Interesting, does it accept a combination of both device and kernel module? Note that the kernel module (*knem*) is not related to the infiniband device but to locked memory. So they are 2 distinct pieces of software, the infiniband drivers are loaded when the device comes up. I'll see if I can find something that works with *udev*. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Upstart job for this:

```
# Ensures that the device is up and filesystem is too
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=ib0
stop on runlevel [016]

# Ensures that module is loaded
pre-start exec modprobe -q knem

exec /path/to/exec
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. It does not change. Actually the module is already correctly loaded. The problem seems to be related with permissions or (more plausibely) with environment variables. Please refer to the edit in my question.